# Perfect tense + +'for' vs. Perfect tense + 'over/during'

Tags: stative-verbs

Page 423 of *Collins Usage Guide* reads,

> To say how long something has been the case, use
> *for*:
>
> - (1) *We've been married **for** seven years.*
>
> To mention how long something has been happening, use
> *during/over*:
>
> - (2) *A considerable amount of rain has fallen **during** the past two years*.
> - (3) *Things have become noticeably worse **over** the past two or three months*

What's this difference due to? different type of verbs?

Comment: This may be doctoral-thesis level.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't the key here that for both examples the author is using the present perfect?

Comment: There are 3 examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth both cases,  _how long something has been the case_ and  _how long something has been happening_

Comment: That analysis and language is not sufficiently precise. See my comment below, for some introductory thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the aspectual character of the situation.

In the first, there is a steady state of being married, hence *for*.

In the second two examples there is a progressive change *becoming worse* (presumably continuously in small increments) totaling up to a noticeable change, and instances of amounts of rain falling totaling up to *a considerable amount* in a certain timeframe, hence *during* or *over*.

It's the interpretation of the situation that determines the choice of preposition.

We could use the same verbs and switch the prepositions.

> We've been married three times over the past seven years.
>
> Things have become noticeably worse for the past two or three months.
>
> A considerable amount of rain has fallen for the past two years.

The steady state in the last sentence being a considerable amount of rain falling every year for the past two years.

Comment: Isn't the key here that for both examples the author is using the present perfect?

Comment: Fumblefingers doesn't agree with you https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/282473/perfect-tense-for-vs-perfect-tense-over-during

Comment: I see no conflict between that comment and this answer. Both pointed out that we may switch one preposition for another in certain situations. I also agree that in certain situations the interpretation will be similar regardless of which preposition is used. Where this answer goes one step further is pointing out that the aspectual interpretation of certain situations can be affected by the choice of preposition, and certain situations disallow one or more choice(s) of preposition due to the way in which the situation is understood to develop over time.

Comment: Yes, I'd say analysis has to focus on the aspectual. (1) (being married) is durative over the 7-year period. (2) is difficult. I'd say it's summative, though almost certainly the events involved were iterative. It's not a progressive change that is highlighted (though a cumulative bar chart of fallen rain would do so), rather a final announcement of the 2 years' precipitation total. (3) certainly speaks directly of a gradual transformation.  I'd say 'during' and 'over' can be swapped here, but the Collins' analysis needs refining. 'Over the exam, my pen broke' doesn't work, for instance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _Over **the course of** the exam, it broke_ ?

Comment: @GJC 'Over the course of' is not 'over', but a fixed expression with not necessarily (in fact, obviously not) the same grammatical requirements.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also variants such as _**in/during** the course of_: [These phrases have been criticized as needlessly wordy ( in or during alone are adequate), but they have an emphatic rhythm that keeps them alive](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+course+of)